# Entity Framework Nullable Column not in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, nullable

I have a Useraccess Class:

```
public class UserAccess : CloneableBaseEntity<UserAccess>
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int? SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public int? CostCenterId { get; set; }
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

That Class derives from Base Entity:

```
public  class BaseEntity : ObservableObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Changed { get; set; }
    public int ChangedUserId { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
    }

}
```

Site, Product and CostCenter expose this Property:

```
    public virtual List<UserAccess> UserAccesses { get; private set; }
```

When I update my Database the columns in the UserAccess table are still not nullable. What causes this behaviour?

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Comment: This bug was in versions 3.5 and 4.0 , I don't know if it is still in these versions but, a workaround is to manually set these properties back through the Model Explorer or the Xml representation of the edmx

Comment: Since i use code first, i don't have an edmx file. I use the Update-database command to apply changes to my DB.